# System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus System.Drawing.Image.FromFile System.ArgumentException [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]

Tags: .net, mono, raspberry-pi2

Actually on Raspberry PI 2. 
 $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)

```
getImageFromFile=images/complex/complex C3.jpg
loadOverlayImages plant life loadImages
getImageFromFile=images/butterfly/animated-butterfly-image-0004.gif
fn=images/butterfly/animated-butterfly-image-0004.gif  targetDir=images/butterfly  PlantImage.GetFrameCount=5 for file:images/butterfly/animated-butterfly-image-0004.gif
getImageFromFile=images/butterfly/animated-butterfly-image-0005.gif
ERROR: getImageFromFile- System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (System.String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at PlantLifeAnimationForm.PlantLifeImagesService.getImageFromFile (System.String filePath) [0x00015] in     /home/pi/emgucv/PlantLifeAnimation/PlantLifeAnimationForm/model/PlantLifeImagesService.cs:223
fn=images/butterfly/animated-butterfly-image-0005.gif  targetDir=images/butterfly
Unhandled Exception:
```

[image]

This file works fine on windows (DIES HERE: **System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath)**

```
            using (Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                bitmapSource = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this mono bug - https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=510805.
Basically what they say is problem like yours happens when libgif cannot handle provided gif. For example, for your image gifinfo (which is part of libgif-tools package) says:

> Image 8 is not confined to screen dimension, aborted.

I must also warn you that if you do any serious image processing on mono - avoid using standard Bitmap and related classes, they are buggy in many many ways (from my own fresh experience). For most image manipulations I use MagickWand C api directly (via p-invoke).

Comment: Yeah, awesome find, I searched the google on that, great find. +1000 pts
So I installed: got the same response. Fix the GIF? &
Bottom line: strict gif rules cause it to puke on the Bitmap (use OPENCV Image<Bgr,Byte> stuff instead it's more stable, convert ToBitMap() as needed to display? THANKS! 
`$ sudo apt-get install giflib-tools
$ gifinfo animated-butterfly-image-0005.gif
Image 8 is not confined to screen dimension, aborted.
pi@raspberrypi /butterfly $ gifinfo animated-butterfly-image-0004.gif
Size: 148x149
Comment: FILE IDENTITY
Created or modified by
TAKASHI KUMON`